# Recursive compactification: Is the direct limit still compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, compactification

Thinking about the question whether there is something like a “maximal compactification” (the one-point compactification could be seen as “minimal” compactification), I've come across the possibility to recursively compactify a set (so that you get multiple copies of the original space, but it is still a compactification of one of them).

The basic construction goes like this: Be $X$ a non-compact topological space (this is the space that shall be compactified). Be $C$ an arbitrary compact topological space. Then I define a topology on the disjoint union of $X$ and $C$ as follows:

A set on the disjoint union is open if it is either an open subset of $X$ or the union of the X-complement of a closed compact set of $X$ and a non-empty open subset of $C$.

It is not hard to show that this gives indeed a compactification of $X$, and in addition the subspace topology on $C$ is the original topology on $C$.

This of course answered my original question, as $C$ could be made arbitrary large, making the compactifiation of $X$ arbitrary large, too.

But then, I noticed that since the only condition on $C$ was that it is compact, I could choose as $C$ a compactification of $X$. That is, I then get a compactification of $X$ that contains a second copy of $X$.

Indeed, I could in turn use *that* compactification of $X$ as $C$, so I now get a compactification of $X$ that in total contains *three* copies of $X$.

Now I can continue this recursively, and since each of the compactifications is (homeomorphic to) a proper subspace of the next one, I can take the direct limit to get a space with (countably) infinitely many copies of $X$.

Now that direct limit is clearly not a compactification of $X$ (as the closure of each copy of $X$ only covers the earlier copies of $X$), however is it at least still a compact set (and thus a proper “seed” for another round of recursive compactifications)?

Comment: I notice that if $C$ contains more than one point then your compactification is not Hausdorff, even if both $X$ and $C$ are Hausdorff: for all $x,y \in C$, every open set that contains $x$ and every open set that contains $y$ have nonempty intersection. Constructions like yours may indeed be the reason that compactification operations are usually required to preserve the Hausdorff property.

Comment: To add to what Lee Mosher said, if you require your compactifications to be Hausdorff, then there is a very natural "maximal compactification", the [Stone-Cech compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification).

Comment: @LeeMosher: Well, it was not my intention to make it Hausdorff (or *any* other condition other than being a compactification). Note that I also didn't put any conditions (other than noncompactness) on $X$.

Comment: @EricWofsey: However Stone-Cech has quite stringent conditions on $X$ for the construction to even be a compactification.

Comment: @celtschk: Well, that depends on your perspective.  The conditions are just exactly the minimum conditions for there to exist any embedding of $X$ into a compact Hausdorff space at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequential direct limits are almost never compact.  In particular, a direct limit of a sequence of inclusions of $T_1$ spaces is never compact (unless the sequence eventually stabilizes); see [Compact subset in colimit of spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584667/compact-subset-in-colimit-of-spaces).  So, if the initial compactification you use is $T_1$, then your direct limit will not be compact.